# In QFT, why do fermions have to anticommute in order to insure causality?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, special-relativity, commutator, causality, anticommutator

I have seen [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/53148/in-qft-why-does-a-vanishing-commutator-ensure-causality) and I believe I understand the answer to it. However, AFAIK, only for bosons the causality condition is a vanishing commutator. For fermions we expect the *anticommutator* $[\phi,\phi^\dagger]_+$ to turn zero. The answer given to the question above does not seem to address this.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/17893/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 5):

Here is the formal answer on your question based on particular result of Pauli theorem. Calculations are rather cumbersome, but they are general.

**Arbitrary fermionic field (with invariance under discrete transformations of the Lorentz group)**

It can be shown that each Poincaré-covariant fermion field with half-integer spin $s = n + \frac{1}{2}$ and mass $m$ can be represented as
$$
\tag 1 \hat{\varphi}_{a} = \sum_{\sigma = -s}^{s}\int \frac{d^{3}\mathbf p}{\sqrt{(2 \pi )^{3}2E_{\mathbf p}}}\left( u_{a}^{\sigma }(\mathbf p)\hat{a}_{\sigma}(\mathbf p)e^{-ipx} + v_{a}^{\sigma } (\mathbf p)\hat{b}^{\dagger}_{\sigma}(\mathbf p)e^{ipx}\right),
$$
where
$$
\tag 2 \hat{\varphi}_{a} = \hat{\varphi}_{\mu_{0}...\mu_{n}} = \begin{pmatrix}\hat{\psi}_{\mu_{0}...\mu_{n}b} \\ \hat{\kappa}_{\ \mu_{0}...\mu_{n}}^{\dot {b}} \end{pmatrix} \in \left( \frac{n + 1}{2}, \frac{n}{2}\right) \oplus \left( \frac{n}{2}, \frac{n + 1}{2}\right),
$$
$b, \dot{b}$ are spinor indices, and
$$
\tag 3 \gamma^{\mu_{j}}\hat{\varphi}_{\mu_{0}...\mu_{j}...\mu_{n}} = 0, \quad (i\gamma^{\mu}\partial_{\mu} - m)\hat{\varphi}_{\mu_{0}...\mu_{n}} = 0, 
$$
$$
\tag 4 \quad \partial^{\mu_{j}} \hat{\varphi}_{\ \ \mu_{0}...\mu_{j}...\mu_{n}} = 0, \quad u^{\sigma}_{a}(\mathbf p ) = (-1)^{s + \sigma}\gamma_{5}v^{-\sigma }_{a}(\mathbf p).
$$

As you can see, for $n = 0$ eqs. $(1)-(4)$ give the Dirac field.

The massless case is the same, but $\sigma $ may take only following sets of values: $\{-s\}$, $\{s\}$, or $\{-s,s\}$.

You can read about general aspects of irreducible Poincaré representations which is realised as a sum of fields of creators and annihilators in Weinberg QFT Vol. 1 (chapter about general causal fields). Equations $(3)-(4)$ may be given as the requirement that field $(1)$ transforms under an irreducible representations of the Poincaré group with spin $s$ and mass $m$.

**Causality for fermionic theories and anticommutator**

From the causality principle we must have 
$$
\tag 5 [\hat{\varphi}_{a}(x), \hat{\bar{\varphi }}_{b}(y)]_{\pm} = 0, \quad (x - y)^{2} < 0 , \quad g_{00} = 1.
$$
In $3 + 1$-dimensional spacetime and for indistinguishable particles, the first homotopy group of the configuration space with 3 spatial dimensions is the permutation group $S_N$. This means that the clockwise and anticlockwise exchange of two particles is equal and hence there are only two possible statistics, Bose-Einstein or Fermi-Dirac,
$$
\tag 6 [\hat{a}_{\sigma}(\mathbf p ), \hat{a}^{\dagger}_{\sigma {'}}(\mathbf k) ]_{\pm} = \delta (\mathbf p - \mathbf k ) \delta_{\sigma \sigma {'}}.
$$

Let's use $(1)-(4)$ and $(6)$ for clarifying the statistic which is obeyed by field $(1)$.

We have by using these equations and the identity $[\gamma_{\mu} , \gamma_{5}]_{+} = 0$ that
$$
\tag 7 [\hat{\varphi}_{a}(x), \hat{\bar{\varphi }}_{b}(y)]_{\pm} = \sum_{\sigma}\int \frac{d^{3}\mathbf p}{(2 \pi )^{3}2E_{\mathbf p}}\left( u^{\sigma}_{a}(\mathbf p)\bar{u}^{\sigma}_{b}(\mathbf p) e^{-ipX} \mp \gamma_{5}u^{\sigma}_{a}(\mathbf p)\bar{u}_{b}^{\sigma}(\mathbf p)e^{ipX}\right), 
$$
where $X = x - y$ and $\hat{\bar {\varphi}} = \hat{\varphi}^{\dagger}\gamma_{0}$.

By using the second identity of $(3)$ and the requirement of Lorentz covariance, it can be shown that $\sum_{\sigma}u^{\sigma}_{a}(\mathbf p)\bar{u}_{b}^{\sigma}(\mathbf p) = R_{ab}(p)$ can be represented in a form
$$
R_{ab}(p) = (\gamma^{\mu}p_{\mu} + m)P_{ab}(p), 
$$
where $P_{ab}(p)$ is constructed from sum of summands with even number of momentums and even number of gamma-matrices and from summands with odd numbers of momentums and odd number of gamma-matrices. So by using $[\gamma_{\mu} , \gamma_{5}]_{+} = 0$ again, we may get
$$
[\hat{\varphi}_{a}(x), \hat{\bar{\varphi }}_{b}(y)]_{\pm} = \int \frac{d^{3}\mathbf p}{(2 \pi )^{3}2E_{\mathbf p}}\left( R_{ab}(p) e^{-ipX} \mp R_{ab}(-p)e^{ipX}\right) = 
$$
$$
\tag 8  = R_{ab}\left( i\partial_{x}\right)(D(X) \mp D(-X)), \quad D(X) = \int \frac{d^{3}\mathbf p }{(2 \pi )^{3}2E_{\mathbf p}}e^{-ipX}. 
$$
It can be shown that for $X^{2} < 0$, the function $D(X)$ satisfies the relation $D(X) = D(-X)$, so $(8)$ vanishes if and only if fermionic fields have Fermi-Dirac statistics.

Comment: Minor nitpick: The congruence sign in eq. (2) should be an element sign, shouldn't it? (Since on the left, there is a spinor, but on the right, there is the space of spinors)

Comment: @ACuriousMind : excuse me, I don't understand what did you mean. Did you mean $\tilde {=}$ equality? As for it, I have used the fact that 
$$
A_{\mu_{1}...\mu_{n}} = \frac{1}{2^{n}}\tilde{\sigma}_{\mu_{1}}^{\dot{b}_{1}a_{1}}...\tilde{\sigma}_{\mu_{n}}^{\dot{b}_{n}a_{n}}A_{a_{1}...a_{n}\dot{b}_{1}...\dot{b}_{n}}
$$
(so I have equivalence identity $\tilde{=}$ instead of strictly identity $=$).

Comment: Yes, I mean the $\cong$ there. It seems to me that, on the left, there is just your fermion field $\phi_a$, while on the right, there is the representation (a whole space!) $(s + 1,s) \oplus (s,s+1)$ (note that I omitted the $\frac{1}{2}$ since you defined $s = n + \frac{1}{2}$ and there are, to my knowledge, no reps of the Lorentz group labeled by fourths). These cannot be equal (or isomorphic), since the field is a section of the representation, so I think a $\in$ sign would be more appropriate there.

Comment: @ACuriousMind : yes, you're right in general, thank you for your nitpicking. [:)]. In my notification representation $\left(\frac{n}{2}, \frac{m}{2} \right)$ refers to spin $s = \frac{n + m}{2}$ (for example, $\left( \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}\right)$ corresponds to vector field with spin $s = 1$ as well as to spinor $\psi_{a \dot {b}}$). I have corrected eq. $(2)$.

Comment: Could it be that the contraction $\hat{\varphi}^{\mu_j}_{\mu_1...\mu_j...\mu_n}$ in equation $(4)$ is a typo?

Comment: @Konstantin : yes, there must be $\partial^{\mu_{j}}\hat{\varphi}_{\mu_{1}...\mu_{j}...\mu_{n}} = 0$ instead of this contraction.

Comment: Andrew McAddams: "_From the causality principle we must have [... eq.] $(5)$._"
-- Can you please give more detailed justification of that? (Or is there perhaps already some PhysSE-Q&A treatment of this particular point as rigorous as your answer to the OP question seems otherwise?)

Comment: @user12262 : if I understand correctly, the OP claims that he understand the answer on the question linked in his question post. The question is about eq. $(5)$.